# Angular formgroup level validation error path

Tags: angular, validation

Can you tell me in the form group level, how can i get the passwordMatchValidator error, please?

```
HTML:

<input>*****</input>
<mat-error *ngIf="form.errors.mismatch">
mismatch error
</mat-error>

TYPESCRIPT:

const form = new FormGroup({
  password: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(2)),
  passwordConfirm: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(2)),
}, passwordMatchValidator);


function passwordMatchValidator(g: FormGroup) {
   return g.get('password').value === g.get('passwordConfirm').value
      ? null : {'mismatch': true};
}
```

Comment: no one knows how to do it?

Comment: Do you want to perform password match on button click or while type password ?

Comment: Yes, but i want to display the mismatch error under the password field.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked password and confirm password based on while type confirm password...

**HTML** file ...

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control input-underline input-lg" id="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="password" formControlName="confirmPassword" class="form-control input-underline input-lg" id="confirmPassword" (input)="checkPassword()" placeholder="Repeat Password">
</div>                    

<div *ngIf="passwordNotMatched">Password and confirmPassword is not matched</div>
```

**In .ts** file...

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({                        
        name: ['', [Validators.required]],
        email: ['', [Validators.required]],
        password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
        confirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]]
    });
}

get f() { return this.registerForm.controls; }

checkPassword(){
    console.log("Password : ",this.registerForm.value.password);
    console.log("Conform : " , this.registerForm.value.confirmPassword);
    if(this.registerForm.value.password == this.registerForm.value.confirmPassword){
       this.passwordNotMatched = false; 
    }else{
        this.passwordNotMatched = true;
    }        
}
```

**While password is not matched ...**

[image: Password not matched]

**When password matched ...**

[image]

To set in `<mat-error>` :

```
<div class="example-container">
   <mat-form-field>
     <input type="password" formControlName="confirmPassword" class="form-control input-underline input-lg" id="confirmPassword" (input)="checkPassword()" placeholder="Repeat Password">
     <mat-error *ngIf="passwordNotMatched">Password and confirmPassword is not matched</mat-error>
   </mat-form-field>
 </div>
```

Note: The above `<mat-error>` code is just for your reference , It is untested code due to not install material in my project.

Comment: Good idea! i will try this circumvention, but can we create a directive for it? I tried to create a directive with another password as parameter, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @pierre Thanks for appreciate my idea . And yes you can set your `directive` if you want to change the behavior of the dom. But I believe in  make it easy and do it easy. Then it's up to you...

Comment: It works with div, but with Material component "mat-error", it doesn't work.

Comment: @pierre Please view this https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview . It may help you.

Comment: @pierre I have update my answer with `<mat-error>` for your reference. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forgot to add "this" (It's a part of a Component class isn't it?):

```
const form = new FormGroup({
  password: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(2)),
  passwordConfirm: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(2)),
}, this.passwordMatchValidator);
```